# Как задать штрихкод модификации JSON API в МойСклад?

Tags: мойсклад-api, moysklad-pos-api

Создаю модификации запросом:

```
$send_data = array (
    'characteristics' => 
        array (
            0 => 
                array (
                    'id' => '****',
                    'value' => '****'
                ),
        ),
    'product' => 
        array (
            'meta' => 
                array (
                    'href' => 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/'.****,
                    'metadataHref' => 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/metadata',
                    'type' => 'product',
                    'mediaType' => 'application/json',
                ),
        ),
);
$content=json_encode($send_data);
```

Как прописать, чтобы мордификация создавалась с заданным  штрихкодом в формате Code128?
Прописал метку moysklad-pos-api, т.к. предлагаемая на сайте МойСклад метка moysklad-json-api недоступна.

Answer (score 0):

Разделение штрихкодов на типы есть в remap 1.2 - https://moysklad.github.io/java-remap-1.2-doc/api/remap/1.2/ru/#bbd0ba3789 .

Оно приватное, но скоро выходит в релиз. Через 1.1 штрихкоды определнного типа нельзя создать.